# Odd Output in Java (noobie error most likely)

Tags: java, output

This will be my second question on here; I try not to ask because I don't fancy receiving help for my homework. But I'm just plain stuck.

I'm currently writing a program that stores and updates information for some example bank accounts. My issue is that, somehow, my output has two decimal points.

**Example:
"2000.02008.3333333333333"**

Side notes: I'm in a Tier II java course, so yes, my code isn't the prettiest. Also, please only offer hints as to where I should make changes. As I said earlier, I try really hard not to ask for help and I don't want my request for help to be misconstrued as cheating. Finally, I do know about syso formatting and will be doing that with the Title information in my driver. The way I did it in there was just faster for me at the time while I fleshed out the rest of the details.

Many thanks in advance to any help provided!

Here's my current code:

```
public class SavingsAccount
{
  private static double annualInterestRate;
  private final int ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
  private double balance;

  public SavingsAccount(int ACCOUNT_NUMBER, double balance)
  {
    this.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public static double setAnnualInterestRate(double aIR)
  {
    annualInterestRate = aIR;
    return annualInterestRate;
  }

  public int getAccountNumber()
  {
    return ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
  }

  public double getBalance()
  {
    return balance;
  }

  public double addMonthlyInterest()
  {
    balance += (balance * annualInterestRate / 12);
    return balance;
  }
}
```

DRIVER

```
public class Chapter13
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double annualInterestRate = .05;

    SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(10002, 2000);
    SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(10003, 3000);
    SavingsAccount.setAnnualInterestRate(annualInterestRate);
    System.out.println("Month    Acount#    Balance     Account#     Balance");

    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(i + "    " + saver1.getBalance() + 
          saver1.addMonthlyInterest());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `balance` and `annualInterestRate` are getting printed without any space between them. Add a tab or space between them so that they are printed separately.

```
System.out.println(i + "    " + saver1.getBalance() + "\t" // tab
          saver1.addMonthlyInterest());
System.out.println(i + "    " + saver1.getBalance() + " " // space
          saver1.addMonthlyInterest());
```

Comment: This is from one of the first exercises in Java for a new student. I did the same book and this problem was usually do a student rushing ahead not reading or understanding but just wanting quick answers.

Comment: I would upvote but I do not have enough reputation yet; this is exactly what was going on!!!! Thank you very much! Do you know why it was using a period when no space was in place? Is that some sort of Java convention?

Comment: @ZachFiedler - No it doesn't use a period as a default separator. Both balance and annualInterestRate are double values and thus they have the decimal point in them. Since both got printed without a space, you could see both the number, with each of their decimal points in place.

Comment: user2860598 - I've read all the chapters in my book to this point, and all the code there was written on my own. Is it so hard to believe that I did not know a concept like this? Also, note that I even stated I wasn't looking for outright answers, but rather a hint as to where I was wrong at.

Comment: @user2860598 - Not really sure what you meant, but nonetheless, I really doubt if Zach was looking for answers without attempting anything. It was a genuine(though a bit silly) mistake and there's no harm and let the OP know that it was only the printing which was a problem and nothing else. Anyways, its your vote and you're free to cast it. No issues! :)

Comment: @R.J Ah, I do see that now! I have some output from the instructor that I'm trying to match with and the first number was coming up right. I guess I was just getting too caught up in the double decimal thing to really notice they are all there, even without the formatting. Thank you very much again!

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I will be doing so in about 1 minute when the system lets me, I guess the mods didn't think someone would get help this quickly, heh

Comment: Alright, solution marked. Thanks again for the second set of eyes/wisdom!

Comment: @ZachFiedler - [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50703/216721) will explain why the time limit on accepting answers was implemented! :)

Comment: @R.J - That solves that mystery. Makes sense too, I mean, I was able to test and implement your solution in moments. But, then again, this is a beginner's Java question, heh!